# response data from Axios converts my JSON in an Object object

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to make a request from the backend using Axios, this is the data that is requested

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ed99cd7972ceb1e203ff3d4",
        "model": "76 Runer Nylonmedieval Blue-grey Violet ",
        "code": "352077-14",
        "brand": "PUMA",
        "description": "Corres mucho",
        "value": 119000,
        "size": 11,
        "stock": 50,
        "date": "2020-06-05T01:14:17.000Z",
        "image": "upload\\352077-14.jpg",
        "total": 714000
    },
    {
        "_id": "5edc01f0efed972e1c13c76e",
        "model": "Force",
        "code": "200-1142",
        "brand": "Reebok",
        "description": "Perfectos para realizar crossfit, con dos agarres laterales perfectos para Rope Climbing",
        "value": 310000,
        "size": 45,
        "stock": 20,
        "date": "2020-06-06T20:50:44.000Z",
        "image": "upload\\Screenshot_8.png",
        "total": 1240000
    },
    {
        "_id": "5edc0163efed972e1c13c76c",
        "model": "Elegant",
        "code": "2002-1",
        "brand": "Velez",
        "description": "comodos y perfectos para ocasiones especiales ",
        "value": 340000,
        "size": 41,
        "stock": 13,
        "date": "2020-06-06T20:48:26.000Z",
        "image": "upload\\Screenshot_1.png",
        "total": 680000
    }
]
```

But when I try to console.log it in my page I just get as a response "data [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" so I can't use any of the json data. This is the axios request in the frontend:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/carProducts/'+ID.userid)
            .then(res =>{
                console.log('data '+res.data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the data perfectly. the thing is you are logging it ***wrong***.

When you concatenate string with object , output looks like this `data [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Try passing data as param. You will see the data

```
 console.log('data ',res.data)
```

```js
let data={'name':'trevor'}
console.log("Details"+data)
console.log("Difference")
console.log("Details",data)
```